# Analyzing Token Data from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I'm a relative python noob and also new to natural language processing (NLP).

I have dataframe containing names and sales. I want to: 1) break out all the tokens and 2) aggregate sales by each token.

Here's an example of the dataframe:

```
name    sales
Mike Smith  5
Mike Jones  3
Mary Jane   4
```

Here's the desired output:

```
token   sales
mike    8
mary    4
Smith   5
Jones   3
Jane    4
```

Thoughts on what to do? I'm using Python.

Comment: Do you already have a tokenizer of choice? Will names always be `firstname lastname` ?

Comment: Actually, it won't always be first name and last name. there are infinite number of tokens so the code needs to dynamically handle different amounts of tokens. and thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption**: you have a function `tokenize` that takes in a string as input and returns a list of tokens

I'll use this function as a tokenizer for now:

```py
def tokenize(word):
    return word.casefold().split()
```

**Solution**

`df.assign(tokens=df['name'].apply(tokenize)).explode('tokens').groupby('tokens')['sales'].sum().reset_index()`

```py
In [45]: df
Out[45]:
             name  sales
0      Mike Smith      5
1      Mike Jones      3
2       Mary Jane      4
3  Mary Anne Jane      1

In [46]: df.assign(tokens=df['name'].apply(tokenize)).explode('tokens').groupby('tokens')['sales'].sum().reset_index()
Out[46]:
  tokens  sales
0   anne      1
1   jane      5
2  jones      3
3   mary      5
4   mike      8
5  smith      5
```

**Explanation**

1. The assign step creates a column called `tokens` that applies the `tokenize` functio

**Note**:  For this particular `tokenize` function - you can use `df['name'].str.lower().str.split()` - however this won't generalize to custom tokenizers hence the `.apply(tokenize)`

this generates a df that looks like

```py
             name  sales              tokens
0      Mike Smith      5       [mike, smith]
1      Mike Jones      3       [mike, jones]
2       Mary Jane      4        [mary, jane]
3  Mary Anne Jane      1  [mary, anne, jane]
```

2. use `df.explode` on this to get

```py
             name  sales tokens
0      Mike Smith      5   mike
0      Mike Smith      5  smith
1      Mike Jones      3   mike
1      Mike Jones      3  jones
2       Mary Jane      4   mary
2       Mary Jane      4   jane
3  Mary Anne Jane      1   mary
3  Mary Anne Jane      1   anne
3  Mary Anne Jane      1   jane
```

3. last step is just a groupy-agg step.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you put the code all in one place? It's hard for me understand the code examples when they're broken out.

Comment: it's there in the first half: `df.assign(tokens=df['name'].apply(tokenize)).explode('tokens').groupby('tokens')['sales'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: thank you. I'm not clear where the function tokenize goes.

Comment: `tokenize` is just a **placeholder** function that takes in a string and returns a list of tokens. I used a very basic one that just lowercases and splits on whitespace. There are many other word tokenizers available. `nltk` has `word_tokenize` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.split()` method and keep item `0` for the first name, using that as the groupby key and take the sum, then do the same for item `-1` (last name) and concatenate the two.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'Mike Smith', 1: 'Mike Jones', 2: 'Mary Jane'},
 'sales': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 4}})


df = pd.concat([df.groupby(df.name.str.split().str[0]).sum(),
    df.groupby(df.name.str.split().str[-1]).sum()]).reset_index()

df.rename(columns={'name':'token'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[["fname", "lname"]] = df["name"].str.split(expand=True) # getting tokens,considering separated by space
```

[image]

```
tokens_df = pd.concat([df[['fname', 'sales']].rename(columns = {'fname': 'tokens'}),
                       df[['lname', 'sales']].rename(columns = {'lname': 'tokens'})])
```

[image]

```
pd.DataFrame(tokens_df.groupby('tokens')['sales'].apply(sum), columns=['sales'])
```

[image]